# Device is not in required device state: compliant (but it seems to be)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am running a console app via Visual Studio and I am getting the error:

`AADSTS53000: Device is not in required device state: compliant. Conditional Access policy requires a compliant device, and the device is not compliant. The user must enroll their device with an approved MDM provider like Intune.`

However, it seems that my device (the machine running the app), as far as I can tell, is compliant with my company's policies.  I've omitted some parts of my code that I think are not relevant to keep the example succinct, but I'm happy to add them in as part of an edit later.  The error is being triggered on this line:

```
// Build ConfidentialClientApplication
IConfidentialClientApplication application = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ClientId)
    .WithTenantId(TenantId)
    .WithCertificate(certificateStoreReader.FindBySubject(certificateSubject))
    .Build();

// instantiate a new DataRetriever; this is an internal class I've 
// omitted for the purposes of this question
DataRetriever DataRetriever = new DataRetriever(application);

// this method retrieves an accessToken for an API
accessToken = DataRetriever.GetTokenApiA();

// finally, exchange access token in on-behalf-of flow for API B
List<string> scopes = new List<string> { "https://database.windows.net/.default" };
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(
    accessToken,
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
var result = await application.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync(); // this line the error is thrown
return result.AccessToken;
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this error...I'm somewhat new to C#.  Is it possible that the "device" in this case is something other than my actual physical machine?  Or perhaps my version of dotnet isn't correct (it is currently `getFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>`).

I've tried a few different things and looked at this for a while so I'm reaching out to the community for any thoughts if this issue has been seen before.

[image]

Comment: If you look up that error on the web, you'll see that it's coming from an Enterprise level policy compliance checker like Microsoft InTune. You may want to talk to your IT department (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5639dcc9-8d1e-47a6-970a-abcbdbe8baa6/experiencing-authentication-issues)

Comment: yeah, you might be right.  I think that I've seen this documentation before.  Maybe this does need a call to tech support.  Thanks for your comment!